# Color Content Assist XML

Tags: android, xml, eclipse, colors, content-assist

My Eclipse Content Assist for XML files with bad colors, I can not change.

Content Assist for .jar files are with white background and black font is very good. However the XML files are with white background and white font, i can not see what is written.

Anyone know how to fix?

Answer (score 1):

Just find your gtk config folder, then (If you're using Linux) exec: 
grep "GtkTreeView" * -R
Edit file that consist this item and set "GtkTreeView::*_*_color" with your preffered color. And also there is " text[NORMAL] = " option that handles text color.